# No items from ExtensionDelegate array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, watchkit

I'm calling on my `ExtensionDelegate` from `ComplicationController` to give an array of `evnts`.

*Seems to work fine calling `ExtensionDelegate` from `InterfaceController`, both of which are in my watch app.*

But for some reason, I **get 0 items in the `evnts` array when calling on my `ExtensionDelegate` from my `ComplicationController`**.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**`ExtensionDelegate`:**

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

    static var evnts = [Evnt]()
```

**`ComplicationController`:**

```
    func getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: ((CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void)) {

        // extEvnts = 0 somehow here

        let extEvnts = ExtensionDelegate.evnts
```

***This all works fine when I do it from my `InterfaceController` though:***

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let tColorValue = userInfo["TeamColor"] as? String, let matchValue = userInfo["Matchup"] as? String {

        receivedData.append(["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue])
        ExtensionDelegate.evnts.append(Evnt(dataDictionary: ["TeamColor" : tColorValue , "Matchup" : matchValue]))

        doTable()

    } else {
        print("matchValue are not same as dictionary value")
    }

}

func doTable() {

    let extEvnts = ExtensionDelegate.evnts

    self.rowTable.setNumberOfRows(extEvnts.count, withRowType: "rows")

    for (index, evt) in extEvnts.enumerate() {

        if let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? TableRowController {

            row.mLabel.setText(evt.eventMatch)
        } else {
            print("nope")
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `evnts`, you've initialised it to an empty array (`[Evnt]()`).

When you access it from `getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication(complication: withHandler:)`, if nothing has modified the array, it will still be empty.

Inside `session(session:didReceiveUserInfo:)`, you add items to the array, then immediately call `doTable()`, at which point `ExtensionDelegate.evnts` is not empty, as it contains the items you added just moments previously.

Given that you have no items when `getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication(complication: withHandler:)` is being called, it would appear that this is happening before `session(session:didReceiveUserInfo:)` occurs.

If you want to make sure that you have data when `getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication(complication: withHandler:)` is called, you should load some data before or at that point in the WatchKit application lifecycle.

Comment: This makes sense with what I was thinking, you just layed it out more clear and specifically than I could have.  So, if this is the case, I'm not sure how I would refresh `evnts`.  From my `ComplicationController`, I can't call `WCSession`, and I'm not sure how to alert `WCSession` in `InterfaceController` to refresh `evnts`.  What solution are you thinking?

Comment: When I run this all in the Simulator, it seems like only one of the two can be run at once: WatchKit app `InterfaceController`, or Complication `ComplicationController`.  So basically, it makes sense that `evnts` isn't getting refreshed when `ComplicationController` is running.  Any ideas?

Comment: If `evnts` data can only come from `WCSession`, and you can't call `WCSession`, then you need some alternate communications method to load the data you want your complication to show. Alternatively, you could cache the last known data until you receive an update from `WCSession` the next time your `InterfaceController` runs, but I'm not sure how good an idea that is.

Comment: Ok, in the event I'm caching the data, what would be the best thing to do you think?

Comment: (I was thinking NSUserDefaults before but I'm not sure that works)

Comment: *you should load some data before or at that point in the WatchKit application lifecycle.* Complications are updated independently from the app.  The app doesn't even have to be launched for a complication update to occur.